# Excel VBA ComboBox List

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, default-value

In Excel, I don't know how to specify a default selection in a combobox.

In the following image I have a ComboBox in a user form that is a list of Months `(ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "mmm-yy")`) from a named range.

[image]

`Rowsource: Months` runs back a year or two, however in the interests of user-sanity, I want the default selection to be the month before the current month e.g. if the current month is `January 2016` then I want the default highlight to jump to `December 2016` when the combobox is clicked rather than a user needing to scroll to it.

I attempted to force in the following way:

`ComboBox1.Text = Text(EoMonth(TODAY(), -1), "MMM-YY")`, which should have been sufficent, but it doesn't work, in the `ComboBox1_Change() / ComboBox1_Click()` private sub below.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "mmm-yy")

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show all your code - a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: VBA won't recognise some worksheet functions. You can either qualify them as worksheet functions or you could use VBA functions eg: Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) - 1, Day(Now)), "mmm-yy"). I'm not sure what your actual question is at the moment but if this answers it, let me know and I'll add it as an answer. Do you really want it to change every time it gets clicked? This way you risk overriding already made selections.